# HTML divs: Auto height and overflow: auto?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to design a site which includes a content area with overflow: auto and a dynamic height. Preferably, I'd like to be able to put a header up top and a footer down below the overflow: auto div, and have that div take up the rest of the space, but so far this has proved difficult. Height: auto doesn't work, and overflow: auto requires a height so I can't just not set it. Any ideas? My code can be found here: http://abbottconstruct.com/wp-content/themes/abbott/index.html

Thanks to anyone whom helps.

Comment: what do you mean by dynamic height?

Comment: Are you trying to make the header and footer visible at all times, as in stuck to the screen? Try position fixed. If you just want the footer to be at the bottom of the page no matter how high the viewport  see http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried giving it a percent-based height and even a '`position:fixed`' footer?  Check this out:

http://www.d2burke.com/dev/d2v6/autoheight.html

Comment: I have to agree with this. Having a scroll bar in the middle of the page is not all that useful in terms of usability.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get CSS percentage height to work, the element's parent must have a height defined.  As a result we can do it with the following markup:

```
<body>    
    <div id="content">
        <div id="header">Header</div>
        <div id="text">
           Text content of your page
        </div> 
    </div>
    <div id="footer">Footer</div>    
</body>
```

All of the site's content except for the footer is contained in the `#content` element.  This then uses a `min-height: 100%` declaration to be always at least 100% of its parent's height.  Since its parent is the body and has a height declaration, this works as expected.

Finally the footer is brought into view with a negative margin and padding-bottom is added to the `#text` element so its content doesn't get accidentally overlapped.

The CSS is as follows:

```
html, body {
   height: 100%; 
   padding: 0;
   margin: 0;
}

#content {
   min-height: 100%; 
   /* IE6 will need height: 100% defined in an IE6 only stylesheet */
}

#header, #footer {
   height: 100px;  
}    

/* Bring the footer into view */
#footer {
   margin-top: -100px;     /* footer's height */
}

/* Make sure footer doesn't overlap #text element */
#text {
   padding-bottom: 100px;  /* footer's height */
}
```

You can see it [in action here](http://jsfiddle.net/DSnwW/).  If you add more filler text you'll see the footer is properly pushed down.

Comment: It isn't the percentage height I'm having a problem with. I want to have the content div able to be sized to automatically fill the space between the two sidebars and the header and footer. On my page, you can see the div is pushed down below where the white and sidebars stop, while I want it to end at the same spot as these. I did try adding padding, but it doesn't work, in fact it just pushed the white and sidebars up farther. Negative padding does nothing, and neither does adding a margin. Any other ideas? :)

Answer (score 0):

With liquid layouts like this I tend to set up a really basic table(not as evil as some would say) because they do these kind of auto calculations where you need to figure the browser height/width and minus a certain value for you.

Test this out and see how you go.

http://lm-86.com/html_tests/liquid_header.html

Cheers

Lyndon